# how do i send mail alert on perticular date automatically php or jquery with example?

Tags: php, jquery

i am trying to develop portal in that i have to send followup message to client.i have to send alert mail on that date that have stored in database.
when the date come out the mail will automatically send on that particular date.

```
 <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <div class="box">
                            <table id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>date</th>
                                        <th>Reason</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>

                                    <?php
                                    $reasons = new reasons();
                                    $cont = "cust_id = '" . $_GET['id'] . "' ";
                                    $mfetch = $reasons->select($reasons->table, '', $cont);
                                    //print_r($cont);exit();
                                    foreach ($mfetch as $row) {
                                        ?>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th><?php echo $row['date'] ?></th>
                                            <th><?php echo $row['reason'] ?></th>
                                         </tr>
                                            <?php
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                </tbody> 
                            </table>
                        </div><!-- /.box -->
                    </div><!-- /.col -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Cron Job (Scheduled Task)

tutorial to create cron job-> http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml